# Resizing RadEditor's width on window.resize

Tags: asp.net, telerik, rad-controls, radeditor

For some reason, I can't get my `RadEditor` to resize itself on `window.resize`. My javascript function getsCalled but nothing seems to modify the `RadEditor`'s appearance.

In the first place, I thought it'd resize by itself but it's not...it is resizing only once its content is updated from server.

Here's my `RadEditor`:

```
 <telerik:RadEditor ID="RadEditor1" Runat="server"
                        OnClientLoad="OnRadEditorClientLoad" 
                        OnClientCommandExecuting="OnClientCommandExecuting"
                        EnableResize="true" ContentAreaMode="Div"
                        AutoResizeHeight="true"
                        Height="20px"
                        Width="100%" 
                        EditModes="Design"
                        Skin="Web20">
  </telerik:RadEditor>
```

Here's my javascript function:

```
window.onresize = ResizeControls;
    function ResizeControls() {
        var editor = $find("<%=RadEditor1.ClientID %>");
        editor.get_element().style.width = getDocWidth() + "px";
        editor.get_contentArea().style.width = getDocWidth() + "px";
    }
```

Where `getDocWidth()` is returning the correctly modified width. (And yes, the "px" gotta be there). If I check editor's width, it's been modified correctly...I jst need to refresh or repaint the control.

So, on first load, my `RadEditor` is taking `100%` of window's width. But after `window.resize` from `1000px` to `800px`, the `RadEditor`'s width is still `1000px`.

---

**Explicit solution**: Remove `Width=100%` and adjust `width` in the `OnClientLoad` event:

```
 <telerik:RadEditor ID="RadEditor1" Runat="server"
                    OnClientLoad="OnRadEditorClientLoad" 
                    OnClientCommandExecuting="OnClientCommandExecuting"
                    EnableResize="true" ContentAreaMode="Div"
                    AutoResizeHeight="true"
                    Height="20px"
                    EditModes="Design"
                    Skin="Web20">
  </telerik:RadEditor>


    function OnRadEditorClientLoad(editor, args) {
        editor.get_element().style.width = getDocWidth()= + "px";
    }

    window.onresize = AsjustRadEditorsWidth;
    function AsjustRadEditorsWidth() {
        var editor = $find("<%=EnonceContainer.ClientID %>");
        editor.get_element().style.width = getDocWidth() + "px";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX Documentation RadEditor setSize](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/editor-setsize.html)

In addition to setSize method call, try to reset min-width and min-height css properties of editor's div element:

```
$telerik.$($find("<%=RadEditor1.ClientID %>")).css({"min-width": "", "min-height": ""});
```

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention I tried `editor.setSize("800","600");` but then again, the `RadEditor` wouldn't repaint itself.

Comment: @FrancisP, does size changes if you increasing it with setSize function?

Comment: No, the Radgrid stays the same.

Comment: @FrancisP, try to call function for fit sizes in Editor's client load event handler instead of setting Width="100%" property

Comment: You were right, adjusting width in ClientLoad and removing Width="100%" fixed the problem. thanx

Comment: in IE9, the RadEditor keeps getting resized infinitly (Seems like window.resize resizes editor then resizing editor resizes window...). Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: in IE9, the RadEditor's content disappears when I resize the window to a smaller size...what did I miss?